# POCO class project (DTOs)? .NET Framework, .NET or Standard .NET; POCOs classes can inherit from a base class

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, poco-libraries, .net-standard

I have two questions:

1. In what *kind* of project should I create a *POCO* class project (DTOs)? *.NET Framework*, *.NET* or *Standard .NET*?
2. Can my POCOs classes inherit from a base class (that already has ID, Date Creation and Date Last Change) to use with *Entity Framework*?

Answer (score 1):

1. For maximal compatibility, you should use .NET Standard for all your business logic and UI-independent code. Generally, you should target the lowest version of .NET Standard possible.
2. Yes. See [Inheritance with EF Code First](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph).

Comment: I understand, so the ideal is to create my domain project (POCO) in .Net Standart?

Comment: Yes, but you haven't provided a lot of information here. Nonetheless, if your application is targeting at least .NET Framework 4.5, I would generally recommend using .NET Standard for your class libraries wherever possible.

Comment: I understood. I am creating a web task manager API to use with Xamarin and web. Studying ...